# Why doesn't Xcode recognize new created UIView?

Tags: swift, autolayout, containers, xcode10

I'm trying to place two containers view equally half of the screen in Xcode . One in the top and other in the bottom .

I create two UIView Containers and place them equally on the screen.

I name them to top view and bottom view.

When I try to add new constraints, from top view

"spacing to nearest neighbor " doesn't include the bottom view.

Xcode only shows View and Bottom Layout Guide .

I want to choose Bottom View container.

[image: addnewconstraints_screenshot]

Comment: It's possible to create a constraint between two views manually by holding CTRL and dragging one to another in the Navigator pane (the left one). You can select "Bottom" and edit the constraint later.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it . 
I assign them to same height ( height - 333.5 on iPhone 8 ) . 
Then I resize height to 333 .